# more efficient way of assigning same option tags to multiple select tags

Tags: php, html

Currently i have multiple select tags that have almost the same option choices, what i did now is used file_get_contents to get the value of option tags and assign them to the select tags. but i wanted to create a more efficient way of doing this since when i tried to add an if condition inside the file for the file_get_contents to filter out some extra option tags that should only be available to some select tags it did not work. so i was wondering what is the best approach for this?

basically i used file_get_contents to get the file that contains the basic option tags and assign them to the select tags.

thanks
-magician

Code for some:

some.php

```
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
... you get the picture
```

for other files.php

```
<select>
$hello = file_get_contents("some.php");
echo $hello;
</select>
```

now when i add a condition at some.php ie

if($right=1)
{
this is only for this page
}

//this does not work instead it displays it to all select tags.

Comment: What does your code look like?  And what does your data file look like?  Your question is a little vague without these details.

Comment: have you thought of doing anything in the client side to achieve this? using javascript ?
also there in an offset option in file_get_contents which you can make use of... though i accept it is limited in its  use for your context

Comment: hmm. javascript. i think there is a way but i dont what it is. what i did for now is manually add those other option to their specified select tags, but that is killing the idea of having a general option tag page so that you can edit it there without touching all the codes that uses it.

Comment: okk.. you should use php `include` statement.. that way your some.php will get parsed correctly before displaying in files.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: can you define parsed for me, please. thanks

Comment: i tried using include, i see why mine didn't work before. i should assign the determining variable before the include tag. it working fine now. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my opinion, file_get_contents is used to retrieve data from a static file (like a txt file), store it into a string and do further processing.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you would need to use the `include` directive, since you obviously want variables from the first page to be available for the `if` statement in the second page

As the manual states, "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file"

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the file generating the options what set of options you want and to do that, use the query string.

So, first have this:

```
<!-- basic set of options -->
<select>
 $hello = file_get_contents("some.php?o=basic");
 echo $hello;
</select>

<!-- advanced set of options -->
<select>
 $hello = file_get_contents("some.php?o=advanced");
 echo $hello;
</select>

<!-- ... you get the picture ... -->
```

Then in the PHP code check for this query string variable and according to it output proper options:

```
echo "<option>1</option>"
echo "<option>2</option>"
if ($_GET['o']=="advanced")
{
    echo "<option>3</option>"
    echo "<option>4</option>"
    echo "<option>5</option>"
}
```